# Taylor series for $\sec(x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I'm trying to compute the Taylor series for $\sec(x)$ but the derivatives are getting way too complicated. So how do I go about this without having to calculate all the derivatives? I tried to build some kind of relationship with the series for $\cos(x)$ but I didn't get anything meaningful.

Comment: how many terms are you meant to expand to?

Comment: it is $$1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}+\frac{61x^6}{720}+O(x^7)$$

Comment: if you KNOW the answer then post it

Comment: @Chinny84 can't I get a general formula? Like the ones for $sin$ and $cos$

Comment: @Trey That's **very** unlikely.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why though?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\cos\left(x\right)}=\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}}=\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\right)^p $$ That's all i can get

Comment: That depends, but you can obtain a formula containing Bernoulli numbers, or equivalently values of the zeta function for even arguments. Many may not find that explicit enough, I guess.

Comment: @Trey Because nice series, such as those we have for $\sin$, $\cos$, or $\exp$, are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: There is an explicit rule (see 44), but it ain't pretty. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html I think it is more interesting to learn how to set up the first couple of terms, and that can be done various ways, this tutorial might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FK1n3TVQIhc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the Boustrophedon table:
$$\matrix{1\\0&1\\1&1&0\\0&1&2&2\\5&5&4&2&0\\0&5&10&14&16&16\\61&61&56&46&32&16&0\\0&61&122&178&224&256&272&272\\1385&1385&1324&1202&1024&800&544&272&0}$$
etc. Each row is the series of partial sums of the previous row, but
at each stage one reverses the order we add up and enter the partial sums.
Any, from the first column we read off
$$\sec x=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{5x^4}{4!}+\frac{61x^6}{6!}+\frac{1385x^8}{8!}+\cdots.$$
The right-most elements also give
$$\tan x=x+\frac{2x^3}{3!}+\frac{16x^5}{5!}+\frac{272x^7}{7!}+\cdots.$$

There's a good discussion on this in *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik.

Comment: It's clear by going through the table that it works, but my question is,  why does it work?

Comment: @imranfat This is like one of those Ramanujan answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is the expression
$$\sec z = 1 + {z^2\over 2} + {5z^4\over 24} + \cdots + {(-1)^n E_{2n}\over (2n)!} z^{2n} + \cdots$$
for the Taylor series, where $E_{2n}$ is an Euler number; see Abramowitz and Stegun, {\sl Handbook of Mathematical Functions}, p.~75, Equation 4.3.69; and the discussion of Euler numbers on pp.~804--805, and the table of values for Euler numbers on p.~810.  I don't know if there is an efficient way of computing Euler numbers for a large index, but it is at least a different place to start. (I stumbled on this looking for a proof that all the Taylor coefficients of~$\sec(z)$ are positive.)